# FlyWay migrate scripts

Tags: java, flyway

Can you help why flyway cannot install scripts
?

My schema is empty and only one table which create flyway. But it is empty too.

How can I  properly configure FlyWay? My scripts have the following form

*V1__20170918_Initial_structure.sql*

```
18:43:30,773 INFO  [stdout] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 14) 2017-09-19 18:43:30 DEBUG Flyway:40 - DDL Transactions Supported: false
18:43:30,773 INFO  [stdout] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 14) 2017-09-19 18:43:30 DEBUG Flyway:40 - Schema: TEST_SERVER
18:43:30,778 INFO  [stdout] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 14) 2017-09-19 18:43:30 DEBUG FeatureDetector:40 - Spring Jdbc available: false
18:43:30,779 INFO  [stdout] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 14) 2017-09-19 18:43:30 DEBUG SqlScriptFlywayCallback:40 - Scanning for SQL callbacks ...
18:43:30,779 INFO  [stdout] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 14) 2017-09-19 18:43:30 DEBUG ClassPathScanner:40 - Scanning for classpath resources at 'classpath:db/migration' (Prefix: '', Suffix: '.sql')
18:43:30,780 INFO  [stdout] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 14) 2017-09-19 18:43:30 DEBUG ClassPathScanner:40 - Determining location urls for classpath:db/migration using ClassLoader ModuleClassLoader for Module "deployment.mobile.bank.services-1.0.5.ear.flyway-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar:main" from Service Module Loader ...
18:43:30,780 INFO  [stdout] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 14) 2017-09-19 18:43:30 DEBUG ClassPathScanner:40 - Scanning URL: vfs:/E:/Soft/Server_10.1.0/bin/content/mobile.bank.services-1.0.5.ear/flyway-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar/db/migration/
18:43:30,780 INFO  [stdout] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 14) 2017-09-19 18:43:30 DEBUG FeatureDetector:40 - JBoss VFS v2 available: false
18:43:30,781 INFO  [stdout] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 14) 2017-09-19 18:43:30 DEBUG FeatureDetector:40 - JBoss VFS v3 available: true
18:43:30,782 INFO  [stdout] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 14) 2017-09-19 18:43:30 DEBUG JBossVFSv3ClassPathLocationScanner:40 - Scanning starting at classpath root on JBoss VFS: E:\Soft\Server_10.1.0\bin\content\mobile.bank.services-1.0.5.ear\flyway-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar\/
18:43:30,834 INFO  [stdout] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 14) 2017-09-19 18:43:30 DEBUG DbValidate:40 - Validating migrations ...
18:43:30,836 INFO  [stdout] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 14) 2017-09-19 18:43:30 DEBUG ClassPathScanner:40 - Scanning for classpath resources at 'classpath:db/migration' (Prefix: 'V', Suffix: '.sql')
18:43:30,836 INFO  [stdout] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 14) 2017-09-19 18:43:30 DEBUG ClassPathScanner:40 - Scanning URL: vfs:/E:/Soft/Server_10.1.0/bin/content/mobile.bank.services-1.0.5.ear/flyway-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar/db/migration/
18:43:30,836 INFO  [stdout] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 14) 2017-09-19 18:43:30 DEBUG FeatureDetector:40 - JBoss VFS v2 available: false
18:43:30,836 INFO  [stdout] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 14) 2017-09-19 18:43:30 DEBUG ClassPathScanner:40 - Scanning for classpath resources at 'classpath:db/migration' (Prefix: 'R', Suffix: '.sql')
18:43:30,836 INFO  [stdout] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 14) 2017-09-19 18:43:30 DEBUG ClassPathScanner:40 - Scanning URL: vfs:/E:/Soft/Server_10.1.0/bin/content/mobile.bank.services-1.0.5.ear/flyway-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar/db/migration/
18:43:30,837 INFO  [stdout] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 14) 2017-09-19 18:43:30 DEBUG FeatureDetector:40 - JBoss VFS v2 available: false
18:43:30,837 INFO  [stdout] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 14) 2017-09-19 18:43:30 DEBUG ClassPathScanner:40 - Scanning for classes at 'classpath:db/migration' (Implementing: 'org.flywaydb.core.api.migration.jdbc.JdbcMigration')
18:43:30,837 INFO  [stdout] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 14) 2017-09-19 18:43:30 DEBUG ClassPathScanner:40 - Scanning URL: vfs:/E:/Soft/Server_10.1.0/bin/content/mobile.bank.services-1.0.5.ear/flyway-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar/db/migration/
18:43:30,838 INFO  [stdout] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 14) 2017-09-19 18:43:30 DEBUG FeatureDetector:40 - JBoss VFS v2 available: false
18:43:30,853 INFO  [stdout] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 14) 2017-09-19 18:43:30 INFO  DbValidate:44 - Successfully validated 0 migrations (execution time 00:00.018s)
18:43:30,859 INFO  [stdout] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 14) 2017-09-19 18:43:30 DEBUG DbSchemas:40 - Schema "TEST_SERVER" already exists. Skipping schema creation.
18:43:30,935 INFO  [stdout] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 14) 2017-09-19 18:43:30 DEBUG Table:40 - Locking table "TEST_SERVER"."SERVER_VERSION_DB"...
18:43:30,936 INFO  [stdout] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 14) 2017-09-19 18:43:30 DEBUG Table:40 - Lock acquired for table "TEST_SERVER"."SERVER_VERSION_DB"
18:43:30,943 INFO  [stdout] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 20) 2017-09-19 18:43:30 DEBUG Reflections:184 - going to scan these urls:
18:43:30,943 INFO  [stdout] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 20) vfs:/E:/Soft/Server_10.1.0/bin/content/mobile.bank.services-1.0.5.ear/service-web-1.0-SNAPSHOT.war/WEB-INF/classes/
18:43:30,943 INFO  [stdout] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 14) 2017-09-19 18:43:30 INFO  DbMigrate:44 - Current version of schema "TEST_SERVER": << Empty Schema >>
18:43:30,945 INFO  [stdout] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 14) 2017-09-19 18:43:30 INFO  DbMigrate:44 - Schema "TEST_SERVER" is up to date. No migration necessary.
18:43:30,974 INFO  [stdout] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 14) 2017-09-19 18:43:30 INFO  DEBUG_LOGGER:48 - FlyWayMigrator - flywayMigrateStop
```

My source code

```
public void flywayMigrateStart() {
    LoggerUtil.getDEBUG_LOGGER().info("FlyWayMigrator - flywayMigrateStart");
    String flywayMinVersion = FlyWayProperty.getInstance().getProperty(FlyWayProperty.FLYWAY_MIN_VERSION);

    if (flywayMinVersion != null) {
        Flyway flyway = new Flyway();
        try {
            flyway.setDataSource(createDataSource());
            flyway.setTable(FlyWayProperty.getInstance().getProperty(FlyWayProperty.FLYWAY_MIGRATION_TABLE_NAME));
            flyway.setBaselineVersionAsString(FlyWayProperty.getInstance().getProperty(FlyWayProperty.FLYWAY_BASELINE_VERSION));
            flyway.setSqlMigrationSeparator(FlyWayProperty.getInstance().getProperty(FlyWayProperty.FLYWAY_MIGRATION_SEPARATOR));
            flyway.setEncoding(FlyWayProperty.getInstance().getProperty(FlyWayProperty.FLYWAY_ENCODING));
            flyway.setSchemas(FlyWayProperty.getInstance().getProperty(FlyWayProperty.ORACLE_DB_USERNAME));
            flyway.setBaselineOnMigrate(true);
            flyway.migrate();
            flywayMigrateStop();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e.getMessage(), e);
        }
    }
}
```

My properties file

```
ORACLE_DB_DRIVER_CLASS=oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver
ORACLE_DB_URL=jdbc:oracle:thin:@192.168.100.210:1521:DB
ORACLE_DB_USERNAME=TEST_SERVER
ORACLE_DB_PASSWORD=TEST_SERVER
FLYWAY_MIN_VERSION=V1
FLYWAY_MIGRATION_TABLE_NAME=SERVER_VERSION_DB
FLYWAY_BASELINE_VERSION=1.0.0
FLYWAY_MIGRATION_SEPARATOR=#
FLYWAY_ENCODING=UTF-8
```

Comment: Need more info.

Comment: WHat's not working?  Those log statements state that Flyway believes no migration is necessary.  ```18:43:30,945 INFO  [stdout] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 14) 2017-09-19 18:43:30 INFO  DbMigrate:44 - Schema "TEST_SERVER" is up to date. No migration necessary.```

Comment: I add some info

Comment: @BobKuhar 
There are two scripts that are not executed. The scheme is completely empty.

Answer (score 1):

Flyway cannot find your migration files therefore it thinks everything is up to date:

```
INFO  DbValidate:44 - Successfully validated 0 migrations (execution time 00:00.018s)
```

You'll need to specify a location or move your migrations to a location that it is already searching. Use `setLocations()` to do so.

Answer (score 0):

if you build this jar - flyway-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar using maven, then ensure that src/main/resources has a db/migration folder that contains your V1__20170918_Initial_structure.sql

Do let me know if it is able to resolve your issue.